# How can I decrease in app website load time using WKWebView?

Tags: swift2

I am trying to decrease to load time of in app websites. Our application is currently using WKWebView and right now we have this code to load the webpage

```
  var webView : WKWebView  
  if let urlStr = self.webUrl, url = NSURL (string: urlStr) {    
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

        self.webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
  }
```

Is there a way to improve the performance? Would using a dispatch method help? I attempted to use dispatch_async and didn't notice any changes. Also is there a way to track how long it took the webpage to load?

Comment: Invest in a more speedy server/internet connection? `WKWebView` is only a part of the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WKWebView wasn't the source of the problem. It is now apparent that the lag came from other sources in the application and WKWebView has little impact on the actual performance of loading pages. SafariWebView, although easier to implement lacks customization and seems to be slower than WKWebView.